# Server fails with Internal server error when accessed via domain name, but responds if accessed with Heroku domain

Tags: node.js, docker, express, heroku, dns

I have a containerized app in Heroku, it responds properly when accessed via Heroku default domain like `myapp.herokuapp.com`. However, when I try to access it via the custom domain I've added it responds with 500. I am not aware if any changes were made at DNS. The app uses Express and below is the code fragment:

```
(async () => {
    try {
        const app = express();

        // various middleware configured...

        RegisterRoutes(app);

        app.use("/", express.static("public"));

        app.use(["/swagger"], swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(Swagger));
        app.use((err: unknown, _: ExRequest, res: ExResponse, next: NextFunction): ExResponse | void => {
            console.error("ERROR:", JSON.stringify(err));
            if (err instanceof Error) {
                return res.status(500).json({message: "Internal Server Error"});
            }
            next();
        });

        app.use((_req, res: ExResponse) => {
            res.status(404).send({message: "Not Found"});
        });

        app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
            console.log(`Server is listening on port ${process.env.PORT}!`);
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
})();
```

When I open `https://example.com/swagger/` I get an uninformative message, maybe someone could suggest an improvement to error handling logic?

```
2023-02-14T00:50:36.125462+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/swagger/" host=example.com request_id=... fwd="..." dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=84ms status=500 bytes=371 protocol=https
2023-02-14T00:50:37.878043+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR: {}
```

**Update**
It suddenly started working after Chrome’s cache was cleared. However, I clearly remember no cookies were created. Still wondering how far Chrome’s ability to cache can go.

Comment: [HTTP 500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_server_errors) is a generic server-side error message. On its own it doesn't tell us anything useful. Any time you see this your first step should be to check your error logs for more detail. On Heroku, you can do this by running [`heroku logs`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-logs).

Comment: Thank you, @Chris, the logs are added at the bottom of my question. Totally agree, nothing helpful.